# webservices step by step process

Tags: webservices

could any one share links related to apex webservices.
I want to pull Account database from salesforce and should give the acess of this to other platform developers.Some thing like SOAP .

Comment: Shameless plug [here](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/25415/320)

Answer (score 1):

There is a wiki page to help you

http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/SOAP_API

In this wiki in right corner we have step by step instructions on how to start .

Basically you will be using an Enterprise WSDL or Partner WSDL to extract data from sfdc.