# How do invoke an apex method of one org, from another org?

Tags: apex, rest-api, integration, rest-service

I have already connected both orgs using REST API web-server flow.

What should I use, Tooling API? APEX REST? How do I connect them?

Answer (score 11):

An easy and robust way to achieve this would be using a web service:

## Service org:

1. make your class `global` and give your method(s) the `webservice` keyword:

   ```
   global class AnkuliService {
       webservice static List<String> someMethod(String someParam) {
           return new List<String>{'herp', 'derp', 'doop'};
       }
   }
   ```
2. in to Setup > Apex Classes, locate it and generate a `WSDL`,

   [image: ankuli wsdl]

## Client org:

1. from Setup > Apex Classes, choose `Generate from WSDL` (give it a friendly name like `Ankuli`)

   [image]
2. add a Remote Site Setting for your service org (eg `https://na1.salesforce.com/`)
3. write Apex to call the service from the remote org:

   ```
   //prepare the client
   Ankuli.AnkuliService client = new Ankuli.AnkuliService();
   client.SessionHeader = new Ankuli.SessionHeader_element();
   client.SessionHeader.sessionId = valid_session_id;

   //invoke the method
   List<String> strings = client.someMethod('derp');
   System.debug(strings); //(herp, derp, doop)
   ```

Comment: Isn't parsing the WSDL on the other end tricky in SF? Wouldn't REST be more appropriate since he's already connected both orgs?

Comment: no, ignore me - i'm clearly thinking of something else

Comment: WSDL2APEX rocks so long as there's no SOAP1.2 or complex typess involved @PhilHawthorn

Comment: i couldn't get your 3rd point, i executed this apex code of 3rd point in client org using developer console but this didn't work. even it seems like SOAP..have u solution for this using REST , it would be great , if you have.

Comment: @Ankuli what's the signature and return type of your method? Can you elaborate on the error?

Comment: i am using only your code, i changed nothing.
is there any need of librabry or war/jar file to add into project.?

Comment: @Ankuli are you on LinkedIn?

Comment: Yes, I am. but my profile is not updated there.
my email id for all kind of account is: ankushsomani09@gmail.com

Comment: Hi bigassforce, how do I get the "valid_session_id"? Do I have to call the login method from the class generated by partner wsdl?

Comment: @sfdcnoob yes, that works ok

Answer (score 3):

If you are exposing a REST resource you can use HTTP classes to make a callout from the other org. You have to add a connected app/ remote site setting.

Comment: can you help me to write a code for exposing a class using REST resource.

Comment: You have to write a global class with @RestResource annotation. You have to provide a urlmapping parameter for the annotation. This URLmapping is used to invoke the static get,post.... Methods from an external system. You have to use oAuth for this.

Comment: i got my problm, my org was connecting to itself, so it was not unable to find that mapped url, which is in another org. so can you tell me how to do 1st step of authorization for getting authorization code in web-server flow between two sf org .?