# how do i get the sessionId in Apex class

Tags: apex, wsdl2apex

I created a wsdl file from an SFDC instance A and generated 2 classes (ARTaskWebService and asyncARTaskWebService) from that wsdl file in another SFDC instance B.

I realized I have to get a sessionID to call the webservice.
But I don't know where to get the sessionID.

Do I have to also download partner wsdl file from instance A and generate class in instance B? So I have a login method to call in instance B?

```
ARTaskWebService.AR_getActivitiesWebservice client=new ARTaskWebService.AR_getActivitiesWebservice();
    client.SessionHeader = new ARTaskWebService.SessionHeader_element();
    client.SessionHeader.sessionId=???? 

    List<ARTaskWebService.ARActivity> activities = client.getActivities('Client Name');
    System.debug(activities.size());
```

I am doing the exactly same thing as this OP's:
[How do invoke an apex method of one org, from another org?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/25410/how-do-invoke-an-apex-method-of-one-org-from-another-org)

Comment: Is this a salesforce session? If so user info.getSessionID(); if the sessionID is from the remote service outside of salesforce, look at the login() method

Comment: the sessionId is from another salesforce Org. If I download the whole partner wsdl file I get too many functions. All I want is the login method.

Comment: then you can modify the WSDL code and can remove unnecessary part which you don't require.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [FuseIT SFDC Explorer](http://www.fuseit.com/explorer) to simplify the process and keep the generated Apex to a minimum.

To do this, point the Wsdl2Apex tab at the downloaded Partner API Wsdl.

On the method selection step, uncheck all the methods except the `login` one. Set "Exclude" in the drop down at the top of the page that handles how extra classes are processed. This will generate the minimum required Apex.

[image: Generate only the login method]

It will look something like this: (140 lines, 10573 characters)

```
//Generated by FuseIT WSDL2Apex (http://www.fuseit.com/Solutions/SFDC-Explorer/Help-WSDL-Parser.aspx)
//Methods Included: login
//Methods Excluded: describeSObject, describeSObjects, describeGlobal, describeDataCategoryGroups, describeDataCategoryGroupStructures, describeKnowledgeSettings, describeFlexiPages, describeAppMenu, describeGlobalTheme, describeTheme, describeLayout, describeSoftphoneLayout, describeSearchLayouts, describeSearchScopeOrder, describeCompactLayouts, describeApprovalLayout, describeSoqlListViews, executeListView, describeSObjectListViews, describeTabs, describeAllTabs, describePrimaryCompactLayouts, create, update, upsert, merge, delete, undelete, emptyRecycleBin, retrieve, process, convertLead, logout, invalidateSessions, getDeleted, getUpdated, query, queryAll, queryMore, search, getServerTimestamp, setPassword, resetPassword, getUserInfo, sendEmailMessage, sendEmail, performQuickActions, describeQuickActions, describeAvailableQuickActions, retrieveQuickActionTemplates
// Primary Port Class Name: Soap    
public class partnerSoapSforceCom {
    public class CallOptions_element {
        public String client;
        public String defaultNamespace;
        private String[] client_type_info = new String[]{'client','urn:partner.soap.sforce.com','string','1','1','true'};
        private String[] defaultNamespace_type_info = new String[]{'defaultNamespace','urn:partner.soap.sforce.com','string','1','1','true'};
        private String[] apex_schema_type_info = new String[]{'urn:partner.soap.sforce.com','true','false'};
        private String[] field_order_type_info = new String[]{'client','defaultNamespace'};
    }
    public class GetUserInfoResult {
        public Boolean accessibilityMode;
        public String currencySymbol;
        public Integer orgAttachmentFileSizeLimit;
        public String orgDefaultCurrencyIsoCode;
        public Boolean orgDisallowHtmlAttachments;
        public Boolean orgHasPersonAccounts;
        public String organizationId;
        public Boolean organizationMultiCurrency;
        public String organizationName;
        public String profileId;
        public String roleId;
        public Integer sessionSecondsValid;
        public String userDefaultCurrencyIsoCode;
        public String userEmail;
        public String userFullName;
        public String userId;
        public String userLanguage;
        public String userLocale;
        public String userName;
        public String userTimeZone;
        public String userType;
        public String userUiSkin;
        private String[] accessibilityMode_type_info = new String[]{'accessibilityMode','urn:partner.soap.sforce.com','boolean','1','1','false'};
        private String[] currencySymbol_type_info = new String[]{'currencySymbol','urn:partner.soap.sforce.com','string','1','1','true'};
        private String[] orgAttachmentFileSizeLimit_type_info = new String[]{'orgAttachmentFileSizeLimit','urn:partner.soap.sforce.com','int','1','1','false'};
        private String[] orgDefaultCurrencyIsoCode_type_info = new String[]{'orgDefaultCurrencyIsoCode','urn:partner.soap.sforce.com','string','1','1','true'};
        private String[] orgDisallowHtmlAttachments_type_info = new String[]{'orgDisallowHtmlAttachments','urn:partner.soap.sforce.com','boolean','1','1','false'};
        private String[] orgHasPersonAccounts_type_info = new String[]{'orgHasPersonAccounts','urn:partner.soap.sforce.com','boolean','1','1','false'};
        private String[] organizationId_type_info = new String[]{'organizationId','urn:partner.soap.sforce.com','ID','1','1','false'};
        private String[] organizationMultiCurrency_type_info = new String[]{'organizationMultiCurrency','urn:partner.soap.sforce.com','boolean','1','1','false'};
        private String[] organizationName_type_info = new String[]{'organizationName','urn:partner.soap.sforce.com','string','1','1','false'};
        private String[] profileId_type_info = new String[]{'profileId','urn:partner.soap.sforce.com','ID','1','1','false'};
        private String[] roleId_type_info = new String[]{'roleId','urn:partner.soap.sforce.com','ID','1','1','true'};
        private String[] sessionSecondsValid_type_info = new String[]{'sessionSecondsValid','urn:partner.soap.sforce.com','int','1','1','false'};
        private String[] userDefaultCurrencyIsoCode_type_info = new String[]{'userDefaultCurrencyIsoCode','urn:partner.soap.sforce.com','string','1','1','true'};
        private String[] userEmail_type_info = new String[]{'userEmail','urn:partner.soap.sforce.com','string','1','1','false'};
        private String[] userFullName_type_info = new String[]{'userFullName','urn:partner.soap.sforce.com','string','1','1','false'};
        private String[] userId_type_info = new String[]{'userId','urn:partner.soap.sforce.com','ID','1','1','false'};
        private String[] userLanguage_type_info = new String[]{'userLanguage','urn:partner.soap.sforce.com','string','1','1','false'};
        private String[] userLocale_type_info = new String[]{'userLocale','urn:partner.soap.sforce.com','string','1','1','false'};
        private String[] userName_type_info = new String[]{'userName','urn:partner.soap.sforce.com','string','1','1','false'};
        private String[] userTimeZone_type_info = new String[]{'userTimeZone','urn:partner.soap.sforce.com','string','1','1','false'};
        private String[] userType_type_info = new String[]{'userType','urn:partner.soap.sforce.com','string','1','1','false'};
        private String[] userUiSkin_type_info = new String[]{'userUiSkin','urn:partner.soap.sforce.com','string','1','1','false'};
        private String[] apex_schema_type_info = new String[]{'urn:partner.soap.sforce.com','true','false'};
        private String[] field_order_type_info = new String[]{'accessibilityMode','currencySymbol','orgAttachmentFileSizeLimit','orgDefaultCurrencyIsoCode','orgDisallowHtmlAttachments','orgHasPersonAccounts','organizationId','organizationMultiCurrency','organizationName','profileId','roleId','sessionSecondsValid','userDefaultCurrencyIsoCode','userEmail','userFullName','userId','userLanguage','userLocale','userName','userTimeZone','userType','userUiSkin'};
    }
    public class login_element {
        public String username;
        public String password;
        private String[] username_type_info = new String[]{'username','urn:partner.soap.sforce.com','string','1','1','false'};
        private String[] password_type_info = new String[]{'password','urn:partner.soap.sforce.com','string','1','1','false'};
        private String[] apex_schema_type_info = new String[]{'urn:partner.soap.sforce.com','true','false'};
        private String[] field_order_type_info = new String[]{'username','password'};
    }
    public class loginResponse_element {
        public partnerSoapSforceCom.LoginResult result;
        private String[] result_type_info = new String[]{'result','urn:partner.soap.sforce.com','LoginResult','1','1','false'};
        private String[] apex_schema_type_info = new String[]{'urn:partner.soap.sforce.com','true','false'};
        private String[] field_order_type_info = new String[]{'result'};
    }
    public class LoginResult {
        public String metadataServerUrl;
        public Boolean passwordExpired;
        public Boolean sandbox;
        public String serverUrl;
        public String sessionId;
        public String userId;
        public partnerSoapSforceCom.GetUserInfoResult userInfo;
        private String[] metadataServerUrl_type_info = new String[]{'metadataServerUrl','urn:partner.soap.sforce.com','string','1','1','true'};
        private String[] passwordExpired_type_info = new String[]{'passwordExpired','urn:partner.soap.sforce.com','boolean','1','1','false'};
        private String[] sandbox_type_info = new String[]{'sandbox','urn:partner.soap.sforce.com','boolean','1','1','false'};
        private String[] serverUrl_type_info = new String[]{'serverUrl','urn:partner.soap.sforce.com','string','1','1','true'};
        private String[] sessionId_type_info = new String[]{'sessionId','urn:partner.soap.sforce.com','string','1','1','true'};
        private String[] userId_type_info = new String[]{'userId','urn:partner.soap.sforce.com','ID','1','1','true'};
        private String[] userInfo_type_info = new String[]{'userInfo','urn:partner.soap.sforce.com','GetUserInfoResult','0','1','false'};
        private String[] apex_schema_type_info = new String[]{'urn:partner.soap.sforce.com','true','false'};
        private String[] field_order_type_info = new String[]{'metadataServerUrl','passwordExpired','sandbox','serverUrl','sessionId','userId','userInfo'};
    }
    public class LoginScopeHeader_element {
        public String organizationId;
        public String portalId;
        private String[] organizationId_type_info = new String[]{'organizationId','urn:partner.soap.sforce.com','ID','1','1','false'};
        private String[] portalId_type_info = new String[]{'portalId','urn:partner.soap.sforce.com','ID','0','1','false'};
        private String[] apex_schema_type_info = new String[]{'urn:partner.soap.sforce.com','true','false'};
        private String[] field_order_type_info = new String[]{'organizationId','portalId'};
    }
    public class SessionHeader_element {
        public String sessionId;
        private String[] sessionId_type_info = new String[]{'sessionId','urn:partner.soap.sforce.com','string','1','1','false'};
        private String[] apex_schema_type_info = new String[]{'urn:partner.soap.sforce.com','true','false'};
        private String[] field_order_type_info = new String[]{'sessionId'};
    }
    public class Soap {
        public String endpoint_x = 'https://test.salesforce.com/services/Soap/u/33.0';
        public Map<String,String> inputHttpHeaders_x;
        public Map<String,String> outputHttpHeaders_x;
        public String clientCertName_x;
        public String clientCert_x;
        public String clientCertPasswd_x;
        public Integer timeout_x;
        public partnerSoapSforceCom.LoginScopeHeader_element LoginScopeHeader;
        private String LoginScopeHeader_hns = 'LoginScopeHeader=urn:partner.soap.sforce.com';
        public partnerSoapSforceCom.CallOptions_element CallOptions;
        private String CallOptions_hns = 'CallOptions=urn:partner.soap.sforce.com';
        private String[] ns_map_type_info = new String[]{'urn:sobject.partner.soap.sforce.com','sobjectPartnerSoapSforceCom','urn:partner.soap.sforce.com','partnerSoapSforceCom','urn:fault.partner.soap.sforce.com','faultPartnerSoapSforceCom'};

        public partnerSoapSforceCom.LoginResult login(String username,String password) {
            partnerSoapSforceCom.login_element request_x = new partnerSoapSforceCom.login_element();
            partnerSoapSforceCom.loginResponse_element response_x;
            request_x.username = username;
            request_x.password = password;
            Map<String, partnerSoapSforceCom.loginResponse_element> response_map_x = new Map<String, partnerSoapSforceCom.loginResponse_element>();
            response_map_x.put('response_x', response_x);
            WebServiceCallout.invoke(
                this,
                request_x,
                response_map_x,
                new String[]{endpoint_x,
                '',
                'urn:partner.soap.sforce.com',
                'login',
                'urn:partner.soap.sforce.com',
                'loginResponse',
                'partnerSoapSforceCom.loginResponse_element'}
            );
            response_x = response_map_x.get('response_x');
            return response_x.result;
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can use the ***securely*** stored Salesforce credentials to establish the session.

```
partnerSoapSforceCom.Soap partner = new partnerSoapSforceCom.Soap();
partnerSoapSforceCom.LoginResult lr = partner.login('user@example.com', 'SomePassword' + 'SomeSecurityToken');
System.debug(lr.sessionId);
```

Don't forget to add the required target URL in the remote site settings.

Comment: Daniel,  i did get the seesionId but I got error message "Illegal Session. Session not found, missing session key: " when I consume the custom apex web service.

Comment: @sfdcnoob Most likely you will need to change the endpoint URL for the web service you are calling with the session ID you just got. The [LoginResult](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_calls_login_loginresult.htm) will include this in `serverUrl` property.

Comment: Do I change the endpoint from the apex class?  The endpoint in my wsdl2apex generated class is "public String endpoint_x = 'https://na8.salesforce.com/services/Soap/class/AR_getActivitiesWebservice';" and the endpoint in the partner wsdl generated class is 'https://login.salesforce.com/services/Soap/u/34.0';

Comment: @sfdcnoob Do you want to sort this out in your [Making Apex Callouts to consume Custom Apex Web Service STEPS?](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/88401/102) question?